# How to allow decimal only in Sencha touch text Field?

Tags: javascript, validation, sencha-touch-2

I have a [textfield](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Text) in app. But this textfiled should allow the user to enter only the Decimal values, also the decimal precision should be up to 3.

I never able to find the solution for that, All solution I found here and other will only work for Extjs not with senchaTouch.

Any help with SenchaTouch related solution or pure JavaScript solution to do this are welcome.

Comment: You can see this: http://sureshdotariya.blogspot.in/2013/04/add-phone-number-input-text-field-in.html

Comment: This will never work in my scenario because this app is also for windows8  store app, so the user can direct enter the value through their keyboard also.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to use numberfield for this case. Of course this will accept all characters in desktop browsers. But you'll see this only accepts numbers in mobile by showing numeric keyboard.

Modern versions of Sencha Touch framework doesn't provide decimal precision params... but there's a way to overcome this issue. Just place these lines before you set values of your numberfield.

```
    Ext.form.Number.override ({

        applyValue : function(value){
            var minValue = this.getMinValue(),
                maxValue = this.getMaxValue();

            if (Ext.isNumber(minValue) && Ext.isNumber(value)) {
                value = Math.max(value, minValue);
            }

            if (Ext.isNumber(maxValue) && Ext.isNumber(value)) {
                value = Math.min(value, maxValue);
            }

            value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(3); // where 3 is your decimal precision value
            return (isNaN(value)) ? '' : value;
        }
    });
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the [numberfield](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Number) xtype.

Comment: I tried that too but it allow the user to enter all characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
    numeric: function (v, field) {
        var customRegEX = /^[0-9]/i;
        return customRegEX.test(v);
    },
    numericText: "Text must be numeric",
    numericMask: /^[0-9]/i });
```

create the vtype and apply in the textfield.

```
vtype: numeric
```

Comment: there is no vtype support in SenchaTouch, its for EXtJs only.

Answer (score 0):

numberfield is the right one to use. try like this

```
{
                        xtype: 'numberfield',
                        id: 'numfield',
                        itemId: 'numfield',
                        label: 'Number',
                        name: 'num',
                        required: true
                    },
```